# Invoking a method with in a method with out createing a new instance of an object?

Tags: java

I have a button that adds to a panel that adds to a frame.
Now when I click this button I want it to call the method eat() which is a method of the Lion class. Now how would I do this with out containing the new object within the mousePressed method the below creates a new instance of the object each time it's clicked. I only want one instance of the object and to call the method on that instance how do I do this?

```
btnOpenNewFile.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            Lion adam = new Lion("Adam");
            Cat meo = new Cat("Meo");
            adam.eat(meo);


        }
    });
```

Comment: One instance ever, across the whole application? One instance for this button? One instance within this instance of the containing class?

Comment: have you read about `static` methods?

Comment: One instance within the instance of the containing class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define the object as member attribute of the class:

```
final Lion adam = new Lion("Adam");
public void clickMe(){
btnOpenNewFile.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {

            Cat meo = new Cat("Meo");
            adam.eat(meo);


        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create it outside and use it in the Listener but you will have to make it `final`. You may initialize it in the constructor though!